# Talend tMSSQLInput

Tags: talend

I created a Talend MS Sql job using tMSQLInput_1 and inserted my own query. Below is example of my query.

```
if  object_id('tempdb..#lang_guid')is not null 
    drop table #lang_guid;
  create table #lang_guid(
                patient_guid varchar(255)
               ,accountid varchar(255)
               );
   insert into #lang_guid

        select  c.customerid
               ,'0000001'
          from  customer c with(nolock)

  select patient_guid
        ,accountid

    from #lang_guid
```

The issue I'm having is the query pulls the patient_guid from the table but not the accountid I creating that on the fly in the temp table. when i run the job in Talend it returns the patient_guid but I don't get any data back for the accountid. Have anyone seen this issue with Talend before and if so how do I fix it.

Comment: Are you using a tLogRow component in your job flow to see what data is being outputted / returned by your tMSSqlInput component?  If so, can you provide that output?

Answer (score 3):

In tMssqlInput, if you click on Guess schema you can see what columns are detected from your query.

Answer (score 1):

Did you define the corresponding schema ?
In Talend, when using an input component (a Database or any other input), you have to define a schema by clicking on ..., in the component view of tMSSQLInput.

You should have two defined columns in your case.

Make sure that for every input, the right talend Schema is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Check the schema at the tMssqlInput compont (defined against the fetch query) has both columns.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Guess schema which is above Query box or click on edit schema and define your schema 
or you can have a look at Talend documentation as provided below
https://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=11&nbrFields=10&validate=true

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to follow:

- You need to write the exact query to fetch the fields you seek,
  in your case it may be `select patient_guid, accountid from  customer c with(nolock)`
- Then you have to click ***guess schema*** to populate *metadata* for the component.
- You can check the fields by clicking ***Edit Schema*** button in component view.
- Then connect it to `tLogRow` to see whether your intended data is coming or not.
- Other wise, simply write the query `Select * from  customer c with(nolock)` `->` ***Guess Schema*** `->` Connect it with `tLogRow` and see which field your data is coming from `->` then add `tFilterColumn` to pick your choice of fields and process the data further.

I hope I was helpful, please provide your feedback.